# Overriding a table's inline css width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has a static width set with inline css.

```
<table style="width:700px;"></table>
```

I cannot control the markup, and I'd like to use CSS to give that table a width of 100%. One solution is to use "display:block" to prevent the table from overflowing, but then the table cells collapse to the size of their contents, which is not what I want. Is this possible?

[Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/j3pubcpd/2/)

I've encountered many questions like this, but not this particular question. Here are some similar SO questions in case they're helpful to others:

[CSS width and max-width combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936860/css-width-and-max-width-combined)

[CSS: table {width:100%; display:block;} not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809804/css-table-width100-displayblock-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: In the fiddle, the parent div is explicitly set to 500 pixels, while the table is set to 700px, which is causing the issue. Why can you not just do `<table style="width: 100%;"></table>`

Comment: @hesonline - I wish! But I can't control the markup :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CSS's `!important` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

```
table{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Welp, "I swear I tried that", but apparently not. Marking this as the answer unless somebody has a solution that doesn't use !important. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a style that says my custom style is more important than the "default" style.

To do that you have to use the `!important` clause.

`table{
  width: 100% !important;
}`

The above should give you what you want.